# ExtJS Header text treated as javascript code

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am facing a problem where the header text of a column in ExtJS 4.x is treated as javascript code and gets executed. In my application -

1. I have a screen that allows me to set headers for my Grid.
2. I have another screen with an Ext.grid.Panel which is created with the header-name(text) set in step#1.

```js
var Col = {
  "text": columnLabel,
  "name": "c" + columnNumber,
  "width": 200,
  "flex": 1,
  "minWidth": 200,
  "type": type,
  "sortable": true,
  "position": i,
  "index": "c" + columnNumber,
  "hidden": false
};
```

So, when I set the header-name in step#1 like - **Date** then on second screen I see the screen with header **function Date(){[native code]}**.

[image]

Moreover, when I set the header-name in step#1 like **alert("Hello")** then the header-text is displayed and an alert-box appears (which of course I don't want).

Can you please help me to solve this issue. How can I prevent the javascript code as header-text?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how are you setting title for second panel?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by explicitly converting the value of header-text as string. To do this I assigned text property of column as -

```js
text = "\"" + columnLabel + "\""
```

So, my column definition looks like this -

```js
var Col = {
  "text": "\"" + columnLabel "\"",
  "name": "c" + columnNumber,
  "width": 200,
  "flex": 1,
  "minWidth": 200,
  "type": type,
  "sortable": true,
  "position": i,
  "index": "c" + columnNumber,
  "hidden": false
};
```

With this change no matter what the value of 'columnLabel" variable is (may it be Date or alert('Hello'); it will be treated as String only and not as javascript code by the browser)